# Is it the spark driver or executor creates the database connection?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Do all Executors create a DB connection and download the data in parallel? Or its the driver who is responsible for downloading the data and later shared the tables among executors?

Comment: Is there nobody who can answer this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation of [DataFrameReader.jdbc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader@jdbc(url:String,table:String,columnName:String,lowerBound:Long,upperBound:Long,numPartitions:Int,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) explicitly states this:

> Partitions of the table will be retrieved in parallel based on the parameters passed to this function. Don't create too many partitions in parallel on a large cluster; otherwise Spark might crash your external database systems.

Which also implies that executors will have their own connection.

Comment: Thanks Lovei for sharing the knowledge.